# Selecting unique rows using sqldf package in R

Tags: r, sqlite, csv, sqldf

I have a csv file that as ~1.9M rows and 32 columns. I also have limited RAM, which makes it loading into the memory very inconvenient. As a result I am thinking of using a database but do not have any intimate knowledge on the subject and so have have looked around at this site but found no viable solns so far.

The CSV file looks like this:

```
    Case,Event,P01,P02,P03,P04,P05,P06,P07,P08,P09,P10,P11,P12,P13,P14,P15,P16,P17,P18,P19,P20,P21,P22,P23,P24,P25,P26,P27,P28,P29,P30
C000039,E97553,8,10,90,-0.34176313227395744,-5.581162038780728E-4,-0.12090388100201072,-1.5172412910939355,-0.9075283173030568,2.0571877671625742,-0.002902632819930783,-0.6761896565590585,-0.7258602353522214,0.8684602429202587,0.0023189312896576167,0.002318939470525324,-0.1881462494296103,-0.0014303471592995315,-0.03133299206977217,7.72338072867324E-4,-0.08952068388668191,-1.4536398437657685,-0.020065144945600275,-0.16276139919188118,0.6915962670997067,-1.593412697264055,-1.563877781707804,-1.4921751129092755,4.701551108078644,6,-0.688302560842075
C000039,E23039,8,10,90,-0.3420173545012358,-5.581162038780728E-4,-1.6563770995734233,-1.5386562526752448,-1.3604342580422861,2.1025445031625525,-0.0028504751366762804,-0.6103972392687121,-2.0390388918403284,-1.7249948885013526,0.00231891181914203,0.0023189141684282384,-0.18603688853814693,-0.0014303471592995315,-0.03182759137355937,0.001011754948131039,0.13009444290656555,-1.737249614361576,-0.015763602969926262,-0.16276139919188118,0.7133868949811379,-1.624962995908364,-1.5946762525901037,-1.5362787555380522,4.751479927607516,6,-0.688302560842075
C000039,E23039,35,10,90,-0.3593468363273839,-5.581162038780728E-4,-2.2590624066428937,-1.540784192984501,-1.3651511418164592,0.05539868728273849,-0.00225912499740972,0.20899232681704485,-2.2007336302050633,-2.518401278903022,0.0023189850665203673,0.0023189834133465186,-0.1386548782028836,-0.0013092574968056093,-0.0315006293688149,9.042390365542781E-4,-0.3514180333671346,-1.8007561969675518,-0.008593259125791147,-2.295351187387221,0.6329101442826701,-1.8095530459660578,-1.7748676145152822,-1.495347406256394,2.553693742122162,34,-0.6882806822066699
```

....
....
upto 1.9 M rows

As you can see the 'Case' column repeats itself but I want to only get unique records before importing it into a dataframe. So i used this:

```
f<-file("test.csv")
bigdf <- sqldf("select * from 'f' where Case in (select Case from 'f' group by Case having count(*) = 1)", dbname = tempfile(), file.format = list(header = T, row.names = F))
```

However I get this error:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "in": syntax error)
```

Is there something obvious I am missing here. 
Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT...`?

Comment: So I tried this:
bigdf <- sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT Case FROM 'f'", dbname = tempfile(), file.format = list(header = T, row.names = F)) 
but get this:
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "FROM": syntax error)

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` is a [keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), so you have to quote this column name as `"Case"` in your query.

Comment: Double quotes didn't work for me. Had to use [Case]. But thanks for pointing that it was a keyword. And the solution to finding unique rows is:
Select * from f group by [Case]. 
I cant believe it was that simple!

Answer (score 0):

For those who want unique rows using [`sqldf`](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#overview), use [`DISTINCT`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_distinct_keyword.htm):

```
newdf <- sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM df") # Get unique rows
```

[`sqldf`](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#overview) uses [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) Syntax by default.

```
newdf <- sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM df") # Get unique column values
newdf <- sqldf("SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT name) as NoNames FROM df GROUP BY whatever") # Get a count of unique names
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use "Case" in sqldf in R, you should put a "," before "Case". Because the "Case" query is the whole line, you should make it seperate.